# I can not remove duplicates in array

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I've got this :
Table that has products and each product has more than 1 color for example :

1. Glass has red, green colors
2. Ball has red, green, yellow colors

I want to get only the colors only once, but with the bellow code I receive different arrays for each product.. array_merge somehow doesn't merge all arrays in one array.. Please help me to:

1. Merge the arrays in one
2. To remove dublicated colors in the new array.

```
$query='SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT colors SEPARATOR ", ") FROM products WHERE colors!="" GROUP BY colors';

$result=mysql_query($query) or die('Mysql Error:'.mysql_error().'<br /> Query:'.$query);
$num_rows=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($num_rows){
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {

  $array = array($row[0]);

  $colors = array_merge($array);

  var_dump($colors ); 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want an array of colors with no regard to products? Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT colors FROM products WHERE colors != ''
```

I'm guessing here, but I think your colors columns is just a comma separated list of colors. This is not really the best way to do such a thing but anyway... try the above query, then in php

```
$result=mysql_query($query) or die('Mysql Error:'.mysql_error().'<br /> Query:'.$query);
$num_rows=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($num_rows){
$colors = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {

    $array = explode(',' $row[0]);  // your row is just a string, explode it to get an array
    $colors = array_merge($colors, $array); // merge that into the colors array
}

$colors = array_map('trim', $colors); // in case there was any whitespace in your color strings
$colors = array_filter($colors); // remove any empties
$colors = array_unique($colors); // strip out the dupes
```

Comment: this way I receive repeated colors which is not what I want. I want each different color from all products just once so I can provide the visitor an option to choose products by color theme..

Comment: You would not get repeated colors. DISTINCT ensures that you get each one only once.

Comment: yes, but for a row, not for all results. DISTINCT removes dublicates from a product, for example : GLASS - red, green, red - Red will be removed, but if the next product has red it will show up red again.. because they come in different arrays..

Comment: Your query is on the entire table with no regard to products. This is why I'm asking, are you trying to get an array of all colors in the table or a list of all colors for a particular product, or a list of all products for a particular color? If you just want each color only once, this query will get it.

Comment: The query is for the whole table products. I want to take all colors variety from table products, than to filter all colors and at the end to show to visitor each color only once.. I hope now I am more clear :)

Comment: So your table has a column `products` and a column `colors`, right? So then you have rows like `glass | red` and `glass | green` and `ball | red`, etc? Please try running the query above, it will give you the result you are asking for.

Comment: My column Products looks like: id, product_name, colors, price

Comment: OK, but we are not concerned with anything except colors, right?

Comment: Is it possible that you have only one row per product and the colors column contains a comma separated list of colors? You need to make that clear because that is not the expected way to do something like this.

Comment: yes 1 row per product is OK and yes they are separated now by commas - each color. But at the end I wish all different colors from all products in 1 array so I can publish them only once

Comment: I see. Please see my edit above, this is how you need to deal with a comma separated list. Ideally, your database would have a better structure though. Maybe a colors table and a mapping to associate each product with any number of colors.

Comment: the edited query returns Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE and I do not see where the problem is within it..

Comment: Correct code for the above issue: $result=mysql_query
$num_rows=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($num_rows){ 
$colors = array(); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) { 
    $array = explode(',', $row[0]);  // your row is just a string, explode it to get an array 
    $colors = array_merge($colors, $array); // merge that into the colors array } 
array_map('trim', $colors); // in case there was any whitespace in your color strings 
$colors = array_unique($colors);
$temp = array_filter($colors);
//var_dump($temp);
for($j = 0; $j < count($temp); $j++) {
//var_dump($temp[$j]);

Comment: but array_filter() doesn't remove NULL and between colors I have 1 NULL for each color.. any ideas guys?

Comment: string(3) "red" NULL string(5) "green" NULL string(6) "yellow" NULL  string(4) "blue" NULL

Comment: I made some small changes in the last three lines. Please have a look. `array_filter` should remove null values. Why do you have null values anyway? Does the colors column in your database contain null in some cases? This should not be.

Answer (score 0):

Don't CONCAT the colors but rewrite the SQL in a way you get a row for each color. Add them all in an array and run `array_filter()` afterwards.

Comment: I removed GROUP_CONCAT, but still the same, results come in different array even after array_filter() .. How to merge them?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query='SELECT DISTINCT colors FROM products WHERE colors !=""';
$result=mysql_query($query) or die('Mysql Error:'.mysql_error().'<br /> Query:'.$query);
$colors = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $colors[] = $row[0]; 
}
var_dump($colors);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, meaning you want single array consisting of all colours that are in all items and this array has to be unique, you should do the following: you should declare `$colors` out of while loop, and then replace `array_merge` with function that checks if provided colour is in `$colors` array, and if not then add to it. Code is below:

```
$query='SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT colors SEPARATOR ", ") FROM products WHERE colors!="" GROUP BY colors';

$result=mysql_query($query) or die('Mysql Error:'.mysql_error().'<br /> Query:'.$query);
$num_rows=mysql_num_rows($result);
$colors=array();
if($num_rows){
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {

$array = array($row[0]);

$colors = array_merge($array);


}
$colors=array_unique($input);
var_dump($colors);
```

Comment: exactly :) can you please show me how to do it.. the script I mean :)

Comment: All results are missing or only some particular? You are using PHP 5?

Comment: Try to delete row with `array_unique` function and tell me if all colours are in array, including repeated

Comment: Could you provide simple example, because I tried it on my local PC and it works.

Comment: this is how the results look array(1) { [0]=> string(35) "red, green, purple, blue" } I am missing yellow and black colors